# Is it possible to mark an XML node as 'must be transformed'?

Tags: .net, xml, xdt-transform

Is it possible to mark a node within an XML file (such as a config file) as 'must be transformed' and for the transformation to fail if you don't specify it within your transformation file?

For example, take the following *made up* example of a `.config` file with a node that must be transformed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Mark this key to be transformed -->
    <add key="MyValue" MustBeTransformed="true" />
  </appSettings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Because the key value is marked as `MustBeTransformed`, the following would ensure that it is transformed correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Without the line below, the transform would fail -->
    <add key="MyValue" xdt:Transform="Set a value" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I ask this because at the moment I have only seen this to be possible using `.ps1` scripts and XPath

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "must be transformed"? Do you mean "must be selected by an `xsl:apply-templates` instruction? Or do you mean "must match a template rule other than the built-in template rule"? Or is it enough to be selected, for example, in an `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:copy-of` instruction?

Comment: Thats a good question. I'd like to ensure that for any transforms that take place, that values are provided for each of the keys. So validating that an attribute has been set on the node would be a good start I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark a node as "must be transformed" and the only data you have around *is* the XML tree, then you'll have to modify the XML with a mark.

You can do this by adding a reserved attribute MustBeTransformed to a node, or by wrapping the node in a reserved tag   ... .   You'll need to apply your transforms, and then run a check to see if any of these reserved attributes/tags are still present.

If you don't want to mark the XML itself, your "mustbetransformed" signal must by definition be outside the XML; now you need some way to point. You could write down a set of XPATH expressions to "point" to nodes that need transforming; this is fragile because transformations can move around XML subtrees and the XPATHs may become invalid unless they are adjusted too, and that's awkward.